# find the root of the polynomial ?10

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

[image]

My attempt ; i take the root  $a, b$ and $c$ such that $a+b+c =-p$ and $ab + bc +ac =q$ and $abc =-r$, now i used the formula 
$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 -3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2 -ab-bc-ac)$

i got $a^3 +b^3 +c^3 = -p(-p^3 + q) +3r$

is my answer is correct or not .pliz give me some hints or solution ,,i will be very thankful

Comment: As the question is asking for $a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b$, then your solution isn't correct.

Comment: Learn some basic Mathjax

Comment: thanks u so much @ lord shark the unknown ,,,,i got it now

Comment: If you just put your mathematical expressions in to $ signs your question will have a better look

Comment: thanks  for give me some idea @ deniz tuna Yalcin,,,,,,,,actually ,i don't know how to use maths jax....this is the main problem for me

Comment: Have a look here for MathJax guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @you're welcome. It is easier than you think actually, you already know how to show The Power of a number like a^b when you put it in dollar signs $a^b$ ıf you want something like $a^{AB}$ then you can't write a^AB you should write a^{AB}.(for instance) All I did was to put your writings in dollar signs when I edited your post.